# Drupal - Tagging Users in Content

Tags: drupal, tags

I'd like multiple users to be able to be tagged in posts on a drupal 7.9 site.

I've tried the Entity Reference module for this. However, it has no way of filtering the users based on their user type. I need to be able to have filters in place for the user type.

I'm very new to drupal, but even after a lot of searching I couldn't find out how to do this. Is there any module or method I can use for this?

Edit: Also, I'd like multiple users to be taggable in a intuitive way - and not by having to add multiple input boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [References module](http://drupal.org/project/references), it has a `userreference` module which can replace the one provided by Entity Reference.

The huge advantage is that you can create a view to specify the users you need to reference, and the `userreference` module will let you use that view to filter the possible values in your autocomplete/dropdown.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful - I'd actually tried it before. However I'd like to have multiple users tagged in the same input box, as it is in the Entity Reference module. Adding a text box for each user makes for a very clunky interface. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Not natively I'm afraid. It might be possible to hook into the autocomplete widget provided by Entity Reference but that would involve a fair bit of reading the module code to see if it provides hooks, then implementing them